# TypeScript/SystemJS import jquery plugins

Tags: typescript, angular, systemjs

i have an angular 2 typescript application here which is build with angular-cli. I have problems to integrate jquery plugins correctly in my module system.

I read some tutorials an get jquery for example working, but i don't know how to process jquery addons.

Here my Setup:
SystemJS-Config

```
const map: any = {
    'moment': 'vendor/moment',
    'jquery': 'vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'datatables.net': 'vendor/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
    'moment': {
        format: 'cjs'
    },
    'jquery': {
        format: 'global'
    },
    'datatables.net': {
        'format': 'global',
        'deps': [
            'jquery'
        ]
    }

};
```

i expected that i can do somethink like:

```
import * as moment from 'moment/moment'
import * as dt from 'datatables.net'
```

but i get "Cannot find module 'datatables.net'."
I think it is because the datatables plugin dont export any module:
(datatables defition file)

```
interface JQuery
{
    dataTable(param? :DataTables.Options) : DataTables.DataTable;
}

declare namespace DataTables
{
    export interface DataTable
    { ...
```

But i don't know if i should import that...
I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Maybe this could be a possible solution. It works for me to use jQuery plugins...

`window['$'] = require('jquery/dist/jquery');
window['plugin'] = require('myplugin/plugin');`

Comment: 'datatables.net' should be a directory in node_modules/ .  If it's your stuff, you need the relative path, even if it's dot: './datatables.net' or '../somewhere.datatables.net' and it'll get file datatables.net.ts .